# Multilpe screen in wxpython

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

all.
I'd like to be able to switch between multiple screens. Meaning, the first one is the main, then when with a button or an external switch is activated I can see the page #2, in that one I may have an other button to return to the first one, or going to #3, etc. Cause I have a main screen for a big RPM meter, but I may want to see instead all three meter on the same page, or view the raw data in an other page, or go to the set-up page or elsewhere in the future development. I'm using the full screen space for my graphic.  Maybe something like "hide" or "show" a page with an event of some kind. I have a single class script for every pages so far, but unable to group them in a single one. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this concept several years ago [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/). I went ahead an reproduced the example from that article:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib


class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """"""    

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)


class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    """"""    

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(25,12)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class MyForm(wx.Frame):    

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Panel Switcher Tutorial")

        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
        self.panel_two.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        switch_panels_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 
                                                  "Switch Panels", 
                                                  "Some text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSwitchPanels, 
                  switch_panels_menu_item)
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)    

    def onSwitchPanels(self, event):
        """"""
        if self.panel_one.IsShown():
            self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
            self.panel_one.Hide()
            self.panel_two.Show()
        else:
            self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
            self.panel_one.Show()
            self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The basic idea here is to `Hide()` one panel and `Show()` another. You might also want to look at the Notebook controls that wxPython provides as they have a similar functionality.